# Login form inside iFrame - refresh parent frame (once) on successful login?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a PHP login form/script running inside an iFrame on my home page.  I'm hoping there is a way to reload the parent page on sucessful login.  I have tried inserting

```
parent.location.reload()
```

at the end of the script, but that put my login form into an endless loop.  is there another way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you're reloading the entire page, why don't you set the target of the form to be `_top`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I need the entire main page to refresh (to show logged in information), but I only want that to happen after a successful login.  If unsuccessful I would like it to only refresh inside the iFrame, in order to show the errors.

Comment: I see.  Well in that case, one solution would be to redirect on success to a page that does nothing but call a function in the parent document.  That function would set the iframe location to the real success page, then reload itself.  But iframes aren't really cut out for this kind of job, there's usually a better way than tying yourself in knots with iframes.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an iFrame? Maybe you should consider an ajax solution. It has many advantages over an iFrame approach! ;)

Take a look at this website, they even explain how to do basic client-side validation : http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

If you want to do more complex client-side validation, maybe you should go for the validation plugin on top of jQuery: [www.bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/](http://www.bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Answer (score 0):

Try top.location.reload() especially if you are using IE